# If I duplicate a class object in an array list and add it into the same array list, do I have to set it's values again, or do the values carry over?

Tags: java, arraylist

`product1` is an Array List of my stock class, so if I had this declared previously

```
product1.add(s);
product1.get(0).setPrice(price);
product1.get(0).setCalories(calories);
```

Does this also set the price and calories for the duplicate?

```
product1.add(product1.get(0));
```

Or do I still have to set it myself?
If I do have to set it myself, is this acceptable?

```
product1.get(product1.size() - 1).setPrice(product1.get(0).getPrice);
product1.get(product1.size() - 1).setCalories(product1.get(0).getCalories);
```

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: There is no duplicate. `product1.add(product1.get(0))` means `product1.get(0)` and `product1.get(1)` refer to the same object, which is probably not what you want, since modifying one would modify the other.

Comment: @Eran Our professor wants us to code while thinking of objects, and product1 is basically just an arraylist of duplicate objects, like a product line. With this part of code I just want to add another product to the end of the line, and I'm just curious if the attributes would carry over if you previously declare something at index 0, then get it, and add it at the end of the list.

Comment: @TheLostMind I would, but I also need to work on my project, and experimenting for curiosity's sake isn't really a priority right now. So I just asked here

Comment: @JonnRalgeYuvallos - Hmm . I see, anyways, Look at what Eran says in his comment. You will have 2 references in the list which point to the same Object (which you are changing)

Comment: @TheLostMind So if I get product1 at index 0, and add it an the end of the list, it isn't really adding a duplicate, but it creates a reference to the same object instead?

Comment: @JonnRalgeYuvallos - Thats right. You get the reference to that object. You change the object via the reference. At any point of time you can have several references changing the same object. In your case you get the reference, change the object and add the same reference again to the list.

Comment: @TheLostMind Aaaahhh I see, thanks, so to really add a new product at the end of the line, I'd have to create another object basically. Thanks, you might've just saved me a few points from my professor's extremely strict grading standard.

Comment: @JonnRalgeYuvallos - NP. BTW look at copy constructor and defensive copying. They are just the things that you need right now (for ==> I'd have to create another object basically):)

Comment: @TheLostMind Sure, thanks for the help.